# GlassFish installation - Java Location Error

Tags: java, eclipse, server, location, glassfish

I'm using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers Version: Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)

When I want to create new server in Eclipse, first I did download it from Eclipse Marketplace. After rebooting Eclipse, entered link below the servers section to create new server. On the opening window I selected GlassFish and proceeded, then it asked GlassFish Location and Java Location. When I try to paste Java's installation location, `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1` it gives me an error about Java Location. It says Java Development Kit (JDK) is required rather than a JRE. I checked my installed Java on windows > preferences > Java > installed JREs but it's alright. I did actually research this on net but couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are using Glassfish 5. It is not supported by Java 9 so you will need to install [JDK8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and point the "Java's installation location" of your server to the JDK 8 path.

Note: Remember that you need the full JDK, not only the JRE to run your server.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I recently installed jdk9 and then tried to configure GlassFish5 as well as GlassFish4 and eclipse seems to not pick up my jdk. I guess there is a delay in support. I would recommend to try out tomcat8 or wildfly for the moment since it works great.